# how to simulate click event in any site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I tried on some websites on how to simulate the click event , now I call a function that is:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function Loga() { 
    document.xfrmwebmail.submit()  
    
} 
</script> 
    <script> 
        (document).onactivate(document.getElementsByTagName('button').click()); 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body onload="Loga()"> 
<form name="xfrmwebmail" action="facebook.com" method="post"> 

</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

But it does not work , do not perform the button action .

Comment: I am sure there is some errors in the console.

Comment: Reading the docs for [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a HTMLCollection, which is an array-like object, you should probably loop it:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].click();
}
```

Comment: did not work, what I'm trying to do here is a "login " automatic which site or using what is already filled by the cookie and only simulating the click event on the button "login" , for example on page I'm trying (not my ) has only one button